# Duda en consulta SQL en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

lo que sucede es que estoy intentando traer los datos de una columna de una tabla, pero cuando llega el dato por get es tipo string (supongo) y en en la consulta me trae la columna con todos los valores con ese string y no los valores de la columna

```
 if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $category = $_GET['category'];
        $sql = "SELECT $category FROM characters";
    }
```

asi esta en php donde $category es el nombre de la columna (en este caso ID), pero me muestra esto

0
:
{ID: 'ID'}
1
:
{ID: 'ID'}
2
:
{ID: 'ID'}

pero si coloque el codigo asi

```
 if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $category = $_GET['category'];
        $sql = "SELECT ID FROM characters";
    }
```

si me trae los datos que hay en cada ID (ID:1.... y asi) no se si toca convertir el $category a algun tipo de dato sql porque supongo que en la consulta en php lo lee como string

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mejor tu duda? Lo que necesitas son los ID que pertenezcan a X categoría?? Y supongo que esa categoría es la de la variable $category?? Es así??

Comment: es decir ID es una columna de la tabla , $category= 'ID', entonces cuando escribo la consulta si yo escribo directamente ID (SELECT ID FROM characters) me traer todo correcto es decir todos los valores de la columna ID pero si la coloco con la variable $category que adentro tiene  un string 'ID' (SELECT $category FROM characters) me muestra cada campo de la culumna con el valor 'ID', perdon si no es claro

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te devuelve es un array con todos los datos, lo que debes hacer es recorrer ese array con foreach y sacar espeficamente el dato que necesitas que en este caso sería la category y después de eso la trabajas en el if

Answer (score 0):

En base a:

> es decir ID es una columna de la tabla , $category= 'ID', entonces cuando escribo la consulta si yo escribo directamente ID (SELECT ID FROM characters) me traer todo correcto es decir todos los valores de la columna ID pero si la coloco con la variable $category que adentro tiene un string 'ID' (SELECT $category FROM characters) me muestra cada campo de la culumna con el valor 'ID', perdon si no es claro

Creo que aun estas explicando un poco mal el problema pero lo que he entendido es que quieres todos los datos cuya categoría sea ID. En ese caso el query deberia ser algo como

```
$category= 'ID';
SELECT * FROM characters WHERE category = '$category';
/* Esto generara un query del tipo */
SELECT * FROM characters WHERE category = 'ID';
```

Y si no quieres todo de la tabla, cambia el * por el nombre de cada campo/columna de la tabla characters